# Is it possible to salvage what is left of a Raid array? Raid 0

Tags: mdadm

So we had a 22.04 LTS update go bad on our Zoneminder server and we had a raid array for our video storage setup. All the 1.82 TiB drivers are part of that raid 0.
[Picture Showing the different Drive letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvRW2.png)

Is there a way to salvage this raid? If so can I mount it to a folder symlink Example I think our old one was like /var/cache/zoneminder/md/ This doesn't have to match but I would be nice so it would help me remember lol.. Any help appreciated on this one. I did reinstall mdadm.

I was trying to research this on my own but just not to certain with raid arrays this was the guide I was trying to follow buy the issue is it doesn't really talk much about a raid that had already been created..
[How To Create RAID Arrays with mdadm on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Here is the command I am too scared to run but not sure if it would work any thoughts here??

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=5 /dev/sda /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

Comment: Silly question, but are you certain that you were using RAID0? Generally there are an even number of drives for this RAID level (2, 4, or 8 drives usually) as the data is striped across the devices. As it's a RAID0, recovery of data is only possible if you have all of the drives that were part of the original array. With 5 drives, people will often use RAID5 or JBOD. One other item to consider is whether this was built with `mdadm` or if it was built some other way, such as via a hardware controller or filesystem configuration 

Comment: Yeah we really don't care about the data per say that's why we always had done it that way.. Any real events we would always upload or pull to another server that was at least running a raid 5 some where..

Comment: If I'm reading your comment correctly, it seems you're not looking to salvage a RAID array, but construct a new one then. Is this correct? 

Comment: Yeah I think at this point since its failing when I assemble it... I only use this for personal use this isn't for Production environment or anything..

Comment: Here is the commands I had been using though in case you were curious..   ' sudo mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0  /dev/sda /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf'
'sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0'
'sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0'
'sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf'
'sudo mount /dev/md0 /var/cache/zoneminder/md'

Comment: Yeah I may have to just give up on this.. And format everything and recreate everything...